# Netbeans generated code

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, generated-code

I have a netbeans project that I imported into eclipse.  When I use my code formatting style in eclipse, it breaks the auto generated code in Netbeans.  The code is similar to the following.

```
    private void customActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {// GEN-FIRST:event_customActionPerformed
// aaa
}// GEN-LAST:event_customActionPerformed
```

Is there any way to tell Netbeans to go back and use the correctly named methods?  Currently when I am in the GUI Builder, it will not find the method that it had previously generated.

Comment: What do you mean "breaks". The code does not compile after you apply eclipse formatting?

Comment: Maybe he mean that the auto-generated code doesn't work anymore as it appear as common code after bringing it back from Eclipse.

Comment: The auto-generated code appears as normal code, after the formatting is applied in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid altering the comments:

Open the preferences (In the Window menu, select Preferences)

In the Preferences tree, go to "Java", "Code Style", "Formatter"

If you only wish to configure a single project, click the "Configure Project Specific Settings" link (looks like a blue URL link)

You may wish to create a "new" profile, copying from the default (or whatever is used for your project)

When you are editing the profile, go to the "Comments" tab, and deselect "Enable Line Comment Formatting".  That will prevent spaces from appearing in single line comments.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is picky about the comments surrounding guarded blocks At issue here is the space between the `//` and the `GEN`.
The `GEN` needs to immediately follow the comment.

Fails, space before GEN:

```
// GEN_FIRST:event_customActionPerformed
```

OK, no space before GEN:

```
//GEN_FIRST:event_customActionPerformed
```